# How can i generate a Model from existing Database in full using EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

- I have an existing database.
- Create a console app (for extracting just the Models and DbContext)
- Install (latest version 7.0.9)

  - EFCore Tools
  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Run the command

  Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True; TrustServerCertificate=True;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context MyDbContext -DataAnnotations

The above command creates the `Models` with `DataAnnotations` i need.

I now move the classes generated into the correct project one at a time to see how the build process goes and to eliminate any errors.

The issue i am facing is i have existing code which was extending an existing entity via a partial class. An example is if i have a `Product` entity it creates the model as

```
public partial class Product
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? BrandId { get; set; }
....
....
}
```

In another partial class which is using this linked property i.e. the `BasketItem` class has a linked property for a `Product` i have code similar to

```
public partial class BasketItem
{
    public double GetItemDiscount()
    {
        double discountedprice = 0;

        if ((Product.MultiPurchaseDiscount != null) && Product.MultiPurchaseDiscount.Status == true)
        {....}
```

I get errors saying `MultiPurchaseDiscount` does not exist. I can overcome this error by adding this property manually to the `Product Model` and this resolves the issue but i have many other classes doing the exact same thing.

I also noted in the same `Product` model class has the below code

```
[InverseProperty("Product")]
public virtual ICollection<ProductAdditionalDetail> ProductAdditionalDetails { get; set; } = new List<ProductAdditionalDetail>();

[InverseProperty("Product")]
public virtual ICollection<ProductDocument> ProductDocuments { get; set; } = new List<ProductDocument>();

[InverseProperty("Product")]
public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; } = new List<ProductImage>();
```

To me this doesnt look correct as the `[InverseProperty("Product")]` is the same for different fields.

Another observation is some fields are named differently to what i was expecting i.e. `UserName` becomes `Name` and again bringing in a class with this change causes errors.

I then compared this against `Entity Framework 6` which reverse engineers the database correctly and all linked/navigational properties are named correctly.

How could i reverse engineer an existing database so all of the properties are included with the correct names? I dont know if im missing critical parameters to pass in, incorrect command or if the tool isnt as good as EF 6 which as mentioned did convert the database to Code First relatively pain free

Comment: Can't say if it will solve your specific issue but I recommend the VS add-in EFCorePowerTools for reverse engineering an existing DB: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools  (source: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools)

Comment: EF Core Power Tools has property and coumn/table renaming that might help you.

Comment: The tool above helped but it didnt completely resolve the issue but got me further than before. When it generated the classes it had a couple of bugs on pluralisation so left this unchecked but then manually had to remove any plurals in the class names and the readd any properties. Thanks guys